# Sending error in a specific channel Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a `try...catch` system to send an error to a channel when there is an error.

Here is the code:

```js
try {
 cmd.execute(client, message, args, prefix, result);
} catch (err) {
 echannel.send(err);
}
```

`echannel` is the channel that I got with `client.channels.cache.get()`. The channel is the correct one.

I made a command to throw the error with:

```js
message.channel.send('Throwing error...');
throw new Error('Testing');
```

I can see the error in the console though. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I need to add `process.on('uncaughtException, err => {})`

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply send the error to the channel:

```
message.channel.send(err);
```